# Typescript `super` calling from overridden method

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently found issue in  my project, here is example code (angular 2.3 context):

```
export class HttpService extends Http {
    ...
    request(url: string, requestOptions?: RequestOptionsArgs, config: any = {}) { // method overridden
        ...
        return super.request(url, options) // called Http.request()
     }
    getOptions() {
        ...
        super.request(url, options) // called this.request()
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why in 1st case called method from `super` as expected, but in 2nd case called from `this` (found in debug console)?

Comment: Does someone know how to call Http.request from HttpService.getOptions()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` still follows the prototypical-inheritance rules. Meaning it will try to find `request` first in the `HttpService.prototype` and only if it doesn't find it there go down the prototype chain.

Here is some more information about this behavior: http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#referring-to-super-properties-in-methods